# Integration between NAV 2009 R2 and Outlook 2010 64bit?

Tags: outlook, automation, integration, navision

Is there default integration between Outlook 2010 64 bit and NAV 2009 R2? If not, is there any work around to use Outlook 64 bit as default mail client for NAV 2009 R2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research I realized that NAV 2009 supports only Office x86. In my opinion you must write your own automation (.dll libraries) in order to use x64 Office.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dotnet Interoperability in your Dynamics NAV code.
Just add a dotnet var to your globals and find the subtype Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

If you tell me what you are trying to integrate maybe I can help.

Comment: Hello,

I just want to "pop-up" outlook new e-mail window from NAVision (with filled receiver, of course).

Thanks for the answer!